# Bootstrap Grid is ignoring breakpoints when import into Component SCSS file

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5, ng-bootstrap

When import Bootstrap-Grid into an Angular Component SCSS-File,
then the Grid-Column Breakpoints in the HTML-File are broken/ignored.

**app.component.scss**

```css
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid';

// Some styles with media queries
@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) { ... }
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">col-sm-8</div> <-- will be ignored (100%)
    <div class="col-sm-4">col-sm-4</div> <-- will be ignored (100%)
  </div>
</div>
```

**Unexpected behaviour:**

The grid columns will show with a width 100%, instead of 66% and 33%.
Dev-Tools (Computed) shows: that a rule of _variables.scss overwrites _grid.scss for width property.

Just remove the @import in SCSS, and the Grid works as expected.
But I need also the media queries in the SCSS file for other stuff (completely independent from Grid stuff).

*Environment:*

- Angular 15
- NG-Bootstrap 14 (Bootstrap 5.2.3)

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

### Bootstrap 5

After import the following SCSS-files, instead of `bootstrap-grid`, the Grid-System works fine again.

**your.component.scss**

```css
// do not import this:
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid';

// instead import this:
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// Some styles with media queries
@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) { ... }
```